# How to select documents in couchdb that are within a time duration?

Tags: couchdb

I have a couchdb database containing photos, with one document per photo. I would like to create a view that groups the photos based on time proximity, i.e., group photos that are created within 30 mins of each other.

Answer (score 1):

If your photo documents have a "timestamp" element that is collated properly in JavaScript, you can create a simple map that will emit the timestamps as keys and then calculate the window you want to query.

A simple view map would look like this:

```
"mapname": "function(doc) { emit(doc.timestamp) }"
```

Once you know the timestamp of the photo you are focused on, you would have to generate *startkey* and *endkey* parameters set to your desired window.

CouchDB will return rows with the _id values you need to build URLs to the photo docs.

So for an image with a timestamp of 1332927024, your query would be

```
http://couchdb/db/_design/designdocname/_view/mapname?startkey=1332926124&endkey=1332927924
```

Answer (score 0):

Your js will be your map function, and in Ektorp you write and pass the js map function as string(to the code I posted before). You can get the current time as milis, subtract 30 mins, and acquire the time difference you needed(in java). Then you pass that mili time to the javascript. Remember your javascript function is a string, so you simply append the difference you need to that string. Which you can write as follows:

```
String javaScriptFunction = "
    function(doc) {
      if(doc.created >" + timeDifferenceIneed + "){
       emit(doc.photoName, doc);
      }
    } " // of course ignored exiting characters
```

so above, timeDifferenceIneed your current time - 30 mins. Then pass this string to above and get your query result

Comment: I see. You are creating a temporary view every time you do a query. This will work but is going to be expensive. See: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Concept

Comment: Not a temporary view, it is a permanent view and is stored as a document.